# How to query role types in a TypeDB relation?

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

Suppose I have the following in the `schema`:

```
define

person sub entity, plays employment:employee;
company sub entity, plays employment:employer;
employment sub relation, relates employee, relates employer;
```

Then it imposes the restriction that `employer` must be of type `company` and `employee` must be of type `person`.

How do I find about this restriction through a query?

So far the best that I *know* is:

```
match $x sub relation; get $x;
```

It does show that `employment` is a relation. But it doesn't show the role types that are allowed/ permitted. How to query that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
match $x sub relation; 
$x relates $y;
get $x, $y;
```

You can use the same constructs for querying the schema (or data) as you did to write it. So you can also find which types play the roles through the query:

```
match $x sub relation; 
$x relates $y;
$z plays $y;
get $x, $y, $z;
```